# iOS Logic Unit Test target crashes after unit test passes with NSTimer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, nstimer

I want a timer class that can post messages to a delegate when there are 1/2/3 seconds to go.

My test target consistently crashes.

- iOS logic unit test target.
- Tests class that times a duration using a repeating NSTimer
- One test with no asserts. The test passes, but then the target crashes with:

`/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include: line 415:   770 Bus error               "${THIN_TEST_RIG}" "${OTHER_TEST_FLAGS}" "${TEST_BUNDLE_PATH}"`

It seems to me that it's some kind of memory allocation error, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. The problem is associated with the stop timer routine somehow. It's only when the timer runs out that the target crashes.

**Things I've tried**

- Build and Analyze - no errors reported
- Remove -framework and UIKit from the linker flags
- Removing dealloc - this has no effect

**Test Code**

```
-(void)testGivenThreeSecondDurationAtOneSecondDelegateShouldBeToldToShowGreenCard {
    JGTimerController *timer = [JGTimerController timerWithDurationValue:1 delegate:nil];
    [timer startTimer];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.1]];
}
```

**Class Code**

```
@interface JGTimerController : NSObject {
    NSNumber    *duration;
    NSTimer     *timer;
    id <NSObject, JGTimerControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *duration;
... public methods...
@end


@implementation JGTimerController

@synthesize duration;

+(JGTimerController *)timerWithDurationValue:(NSUInteger)durationValue delegate:(id <JGTimerControllerDelegate>)delegate_ {
    JGTimerController *instance = [[[JGTimerController alloc] initWithDurationValue:durationValue delegate:delegate_] autorelease];
    return instance;
}

-(JGTimerController *)initWithDurationValue:(NSUInteger)durationValue delegate:(id <JGTimerControllerDelegate>)delegate_ {
    self = [super init];
    timer = nil;
    [self setDurationValue:durationValue];
    _delegate = delegate_;
    return self;
}

-(NSUInteger)durationValue {
    NSNumber *result = [self duration];
    return result ? [result intValue] : 0;
}

-(void)setDurationValue:(NSUInteger)value_ {
    [self setDuration:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value_]];
}

-(BOOL)stopTimerAtZeroDuration:(NSTimer *)timer_ {
    if ([self durationValue] == 0) {
        [self stopTimer];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)startTimer {
    if ([self stopTimerAtZeroDuration:nil])
        return;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerDidCountDownByASecond:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)stopTimer {
    if ([self durationValue] == 0 && [_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(JGTimerControllerDelegate)])
        [_delegate showRedCard];

    [timer invalidate];
    [timer release];
}

-(BOOL)timerIsRunning {
    return (timer != nil);
}

-(void)timerDidCountDownByASecond:(NSTimer *)timer_ {
    [self setDurationValue:[self durationValue] - 1];
    [self stopTimerAtZeroDuration:timer_];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [_delegate release];
    [timer release];
    [duration release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likewise, timer should not be released. NSTimer is like every other NSObject, if you did not alloc, copy or retain, you do not need to release.

Comment: I was so sure I'd tried removing the [timer release] line and it still crashed. But removed this and hey presto! It worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

There should be no `[_delegate release]` in `dealloc` because you did not retain it.